# Stereo to mono Jack!

Tags: hardware, cable

My mixing desk only supports stereo outputs. To connect a mono grotbox i need a mono signal. Is there an Adapter or cable that feeds the two stereo signals in one mono Jack or xlr?

Comment: I found an Adapter on a local Shop by incident! 7 bucks seemed fine. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is if you are feeding a stereo signal to a single input you need the signal to be summed so you do not lose any elements.

To do this you need 3 resistors in the XLR end, diagrams are available online however its not a simple solder job. If you shop around you can get stereo to mono cables but make sure they have resistors and are summed to one pin. The 3rd pin in the XlR mono should not be used. Otherwise you'll get a weird effect.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. By not using Pin 3 of an XLR plug you're basically creating an unbalanced line. Even if you don't actually merge "cold" lines from the output, it's relatively simple to create an impedance-balanced combiner. In fact, I'd bet that's what some of the resistors in the design are for (at least one will be to reduce the voltage on the "hot" lead by 3dB).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what size you require, but looking at somewhere like [StudioSpares](http://www.studiospares.com) you'll see what is available.  Failing that, buy the jacks you want, get a soldering iron and ideally a test meter and then you can make your own leads.  There are plenty of video tutorials online to guide you through……it's a good skill to have and only takes a bit of practice.